# What checksum algorithm is used by Version 5 Unix?

Tags: checksum, historical-unix

I can't figure out, what algorithm was used in Unix V5 and V6 for the `sum` command.

At first, I thought that it is a simple sum of bytes modulus 2^16. However for a string "1111111111\n" repeated 320 times, it computes a checksum of **28930** (using [Julius Schmidt's PDP-11 emulator](http://pdp11.aiju.de/) for JavaScript). Whereas a simple sum of bytes for it is two bytes smaller:

```
$ python -c 'print(sum(bytearray(b"1111111111\n"*320)) & 0xFFFF)'
28928
```

Later, from the [MacOS man pages](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/sum/), I found out that the `sum` and `cksum` commands had a long history of inconsistencies. However, even the "historic" algorithm versions provided on MacOS don't agree with the Unix V5's checksum. The closest match is the default `sum` command of UNIX System V (invoked on Mac like `cksum -o 2`), which returns the same checksum for this string, but disagrees for others:

```
$ python -c 'print("1111111111\n"*320, end="")' | cksum -o 2
28930 7
```

To be more specific, the `cksum -o 2` and Unix V5's `sum` produce different output for most binary files in the emulator (for example, in folder `/bin`), though they agree on most text files.

Is this a genuine behavior or a bug in the emulator? If it is genuine, what algorithm is it?

P.S. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V5-Snapshot-Development/usr/source/s2/sum.s), if anyone can read assembly code from 1974.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> At first, I thought that it is a simple sum of bytes modulus 2^16

It is a sum mod 2^16, only that each time it overflows, a 1 will be added to it. Also, the bytes will be sign extended before being added to the sum. Here is a "commented" snippet from the assembly:

```
# r2 is the pointer into the data
# r0 is the length of the data
# r5 is the sum
2:
        movb    (r2)+,r4    # r4 = sign_extend(*r2++)
        add     r4,r5       # r5 += r4
        adc     r5          # if(r5 overflowed) r5++
        sob     r0,2b       # if(--r0) goto 2 above
```

the same put into a small C program (use as `./v5sum < file`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
        int c, s = 0;
        while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
                s += c & 0x80 ? c | 0xff00 : c; // alternative: s += (unsigned short)(signed char)c
                if(s & 0x10000){ s++; s &= 0xffff; };
        }
        printf("%d\n", s);
        return 0;
}
```

> To be more specific, the cksum -o 2 and Unix V5's sum produce different output for most binary files in the emulator (for example, in folder /bin), though they agree on most text files.

That's because the original unix v5 `sum` will sign extend the characters, and only the binaries contain bytes >= 0x80. Otherwise, the algorithms should be similar, and differ only with very big files (where the sum of the characters will overflow a 32bit unsigned int).

Comment: Looks like you are right. At first, I got intimidated by the "temporary labels" in this Ritchie's "as" syntax. - I will investigate more on why binary files seemingly don't produce same checksums.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha the cause was that the sysv sum will treat bytes as unsigned and zero extend them, while the v5 sum will treat them as signed, and sign extend them. Sorry for the confusion, I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Excellent! One more Unix mystery deciphered :) And I mentioned you in [my code](https://github.com/amakukha/PyPDP11/blob/master/unix_v6_fs.py).

Comment: I found one interesting difference between this implementation and Unix V5 checksum: a file consisting of all 256 bytes from 0 to 255 has sum 0 using the emulator, but sum 65535 using your code. Is that because 65535 triggers overflow flag on PDP-11?